# What are the wake turbulence characteristics at ground level near landing aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-physics, wind, wake-turbulence

I'm a structural engineer and I need to understand the additional forces that wake turbulence may cause on a building near a runway.

I can determine the natural wind speed and associated forces on the building, but I need to calculate the additional wind forces/ turbulence (or airflow velocities) caused by aircraft operating on a nearby runway.

The runway is 3,400m (11000 ft) long, and the position of the building is 800 meters along the extended runway centreline and 300 meters to the side of it. These measurements are from the very end of the paved surface (which I will have to assume to be the first/ last possible contact point from the aircraft for the design of the building). The runway is approached by (and departed from) that end.

How do I calculate the airflow velocities at ground level below an aircraft (assume an Airbus A380) at the building's location? The surrounding ground is flat and level.

Comment: This would certainly help. I guess I also need to work out the rate of rise of the aircraft, so that I can calculate the height of the aircraft 800m from lift off (or touch down!)

Comment: I'm not capable of answering your question, but some clarification could be helpful to others who are capable. "Wind speed" refers to natural wind (weather).  Are you asking about how to calculate the airflow velocities created by a departing aircraft's wake turbulence (wing tip vorticies and downwash)?

Comment: Oddly specific, but still too vague:  Which end of the runway?  How long is the runway?  Aircraft weight and runway length will affect altitude as it flies over.  How accurate do you want the answer?   And what are you actually trying to do, learn the process of calculating it, or looking for an estimate of something you experienced the effect of?  It might be easier to just measure it…

Comment: Hello Andy Leigh, welcome to aviation.stackexchange. I took some of the information you provided in the now deleted answer and merged it into the question. I also did a general restructuring of the question, to the best of my understanding of its intention. Can you check whether I have captured the essentials and adjust if needed?

Comment: Departing aircraft do not lift-off at the last possible moment, and they climb steeper that landing aircraft descent. Therefore they are higher up when they pass the building. I think the critical case will be the landing.

Comment: Can you say which airport / runway it is? Some runways have a displaced threshold, meaning the aircraft will be higher when they pass the building. Also approach path is not equally steep at all runways (I would assume 3 degrees here)

Comment: My educated guess would be that, (depending on your area) local building codes for natural wind will be sufficient.  At the distances you specify I cannot imagine aircraft wake exceeding the gust from a strong storm.  But to my earlier comment, it might be easier to measure, or even estimate just by the personal observation of standing there when a plane flys by.  If the blast doesn’t knock you over it probably won’t harm your building either…

Comment: @MichaelHall I agree that the standard storm wind load should be sufficient. For the case that an aircraft lands in a storm I would not be worried about the combined effects, as wake turbulence vortices dissipate quickly if the air conditions are turbulent by itself due to the storm.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't say which airport/ runway, due to client confidentiality rules. Thank you for adjusting the question. I will be reviewing the documents that you have suggested. We have built close to the current site, and there determined that the natural storm forces were an over-riding criteria, although we applied them from all directions, rather than just from the prevailing wind direction, and we have used this approach for the scheme design. There is a building on the site currently, and as soon as I am able to travel, will review the structure there and inspect for distress.

Answer (score 2):

I can't really answer the  question with accurate numbers, but have a look at these studies:

1. [Reducing turbulence near airports - DLR tests new
   procedures to mitigate wake vortices- DLR 2013](https://www.dlr.de/content/en/downloads/news-archive/2013/20130430_reducing-turbulence-near-airports---dlr-tests-new-procedures-to-mitigate-wake-vortices_6937.pdf;jsessionid=C04618891AD2CE5500CE158A8AA9E02E.delivery-replication1?__blob=publicationFile&v=11)
2. [Mitigating Wake Turbulence Risk
   During Final Approach via Plate Lines - DLR 2020](https://elib.dlr.de/135253/1/2020-AIAA-2020-2835-Holz%C3%A4pfel-et-al.pdf)

They may be a starting point for finding an accurate answer.

At Frankfurt international airport, they have constructed a new runway about 10 years ago. There are buildings at the [same relative position](https://www.google.de/maps/@50.0480537,8.556387,2229m/data=!3m1!1e3) as yours, (800 meter longitudinal, 300 meter lateral) that were there before the runway was constructed. As far as I know, that does not pose any problems with wake turbulence. However, this runway is not used by the A380 and B747 (but it is used by B777 aircraft)